# Given a family $\mathcal{F}$ of complex differentiable functions, prove that the derivative at a point is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

We were asked to prove the following claim as part of an alternative proof of the Riemann mapping theorem.

> Let $G$ be a (proper) simply connected domain, and $z_0\in G$. Consider the family $$\mathcal{F}=\{f: G\to \mathbb{D} \mid f \text{ analytic and injective}, f(z_0)=0\}$$
>
> Then $0<\sup \{|f'(z_0)| \mid f\in\mathcal{F}\}<\infty$.

Proving that this quantity must be positive is easy, but I'm having trouble showing that the supremum is finite. Could anyone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that $\mathbb{D}$ is the open unit disk.
Note that $G$ only needs to be a region for this to work; I think simply connected is not necessary.

Use the Cauchy Integral Formula for $f'(z_0)$.

$$
f'(z_0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int _{C(z_0, r)} \frac{f(\zeta) \ d \zeta}{(\zeta - z_0)^2}
$$
where $C(z_0, r)$ is a circle or radius $r$ centered at $z_0$.
Now apply the "M-L" inequality to bound the integral.
$f(\zeta) < 1$ on $G$, and $(\zeta - z_0)^2 = r^2$.

Alternatively, you can show that the family of derivatives is bounded at $z_0$ like this (which seems like a lot of work to me):
1) The family is normal on $G$, since it is locally (in fact uniformly) bounded on $G$.
2) Let $f_n'(z_0) \to \sup\{f'(z_0\}$, which might be infinite.
3) Because the family is normal, there is a subsequence which converges uniformly on compact subsets to an analytic function $g$.
4) $g'(z_0)$ is finite, and $g'(z_0) = \sup\{f'(z_0)\}$.

Comment: Fantastic, I knew I was missing something obvious. Thanks!